# How to restart local windows service using PSExec or PSTools

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, psexec

I just want to start/stop service just on my pc (no remote connection) via bat script in a way that **no** "Run as admin" prompt appears. Just don't want to do any manual interaction after running the script. I have found articles showing that this would be possible via [PSTools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) (PSExec or PSTools in particular). It is ok to me that password is visible inside a script. But when I run the following command:

```
psexec -u myuser -p mypass net stop myservice
```

I get: `net exited with error code 2`.

When I try to use `-h`:

```
psexec -h -u myuser -p mypass net stop myservice
```

I get: `Couldn't install PSEXESVC service: The network path was not found. Make sure that the admin$ share is enabled.` I don't know what admin share is, don't want to share something on the network.

Whiles using on [PSService](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psservice):

```
psservice -u myuser -p mypass stop myservice
```

The folowing error is shown: `Error opening myservice on \\MY-PC: Access is denied.`

`myuser` is the only user on the pc, and it's admin. Isn't there a simple solution on this? Other tools can be used also. **Disabling UAC is not an option.**

Comment: Any reason you can use the 'runas' command ? If you use runas with /savecred, you enter your admin password once and after that it uses the stored credentials.

Comment: Don't want to have any manual interaction.

Comment: You'll only have to input your password once, every time afterward is without any more user input.

Comment: @Silbee I am writing a program which is not running as admin and should autonomously depending on some condition restart some service. At that point probably user will not be in front of the PC to enter a password or click somewhere. 

So what you suggest is to use **/savecred** on the beginning (let's say before installation). Am I getting you right? Then how long does it saved for? Will PC restart discard the saved credentials?

Comment: @Silbee One more additional thing: I have tried to open cmd with `runas` command with entering my account (which has Administrator account type ) credentials, and it gave `Access denied` when I tried to `net stop myservice` from that new cmd window.
But  when I run from UI (right click on cmd, Run as Adminstrator) and enter the same `net` command, it works. So what's the difference between `runas` and UI Run as Administrator?

Comment: I thought you could do {runas /user:Administrator /savecred "net stop myservice"} ... It works in the sense that it stores the credentials and after entering them once, no longer asks for a password, however the 'net stop' command doesnt seem to execute :(